# How to play song after X seconds from starting an activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle, android-thread

I'm creating an android application, i need a way to run song after some seconds from starting activity, by default the song starts directly after i open that activity. 
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
           //your code
          }
        }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to wait for a specific period of time in a single thread, you can use:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(millis);
} catch (InterruptedException e) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `Thread.sleep()` or `SystemClock.sleep()` this causing blocking/freezing of Main thread of the app, 
I suggest using `Handler.postDelayed()` instead

firstly add your media file under **res/raw directory**, If isn't exist you must create it.

right click on **res** directory >> **new** >> **Android Resource Directory**

on Resource type choose raw, then copy your media file to it for example "song.mp3"

**the code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Creating MediaPlayer object
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            player = MediaPlayer.create
            (MainActivity.this, R.raw.song); // >> here's choose your song file
                player.start();
            }
        }, 10000); // >> Put time with milliseconds, this will delay the start play for 10 seconds
}
```

> you may want to stop the song by override `onStop` method like this

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (player.isPlaying())
        player.stop();
}
```